# WORDPRESS: Assign Parent Page with different Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am using CPT UI plugin, and I created Brands and Products CPT.
On create product page, I would like the Parent Page to have Brands.

How can I achieve something like this?
Suggestions are welcome if there's a different approach to achieve this, new to WP.

Thanks!

Comment: you could use ACF and create a relationship field. See [this doc](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mason for pointing me to the correct and right direction.

Using ACF is the best approach.

This guide also helped me https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/